Matching icon paths between index.html and manifest.json in Vue app
For my vue app, in my index.html file I have this to define an icon for the application:
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="src/assets/telepathic.svg"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="src/assets/telepathic.svg">

This works, and when building the app the assets are copied to dist/assets, with a filename that includes a hash. Good!
At the same time, I want to include a manifest.json file to make it adjust more gracefully to mobile devices.
In there I want include the path for the icon:
{
"icons": [
    {
      "src": "/telepathic.svg",
      "sizes": "48x48 72x72 96x96 128x128 256x256 512x512",
      "type": "image/svg+xml",
      "purpose": "any"
    }
  ]
}

Problem is, if I put the path as above, then I have to my icon file telepathic.svg in the public directory.
I would like to use the same one as link from my index (src/assets/telephatic.svg), but if I link it like that, the path is not transformed into the final distribution path.
Is there a way to do this?
I've also tried putting the relative src path:
{
"icons": [
    {
      "src": "src/assets/telepathic.svg",
      "sizes": "48x48 72x72 96x96 128x128 256x256 512x512",
      "type": "image/svg+xml",
      "purpose": "any"
    }
  ]
}

but that doesn't work either, since the path within manifest.json is not transformed in any way.

"I would like to use the same one as link from my index" - why? Did you try to move it to public and use as /telepathic.svg ? This could be common denominator for both cases

I don't want them to be on "public", for several reasons. I'd like this to be automatically hashed paths as all other assets linked from HTML. If it makes sense for other assets, it makes sense for these too.

As you noted, manifest.json is not transformed in any way. This means that you need to find vite plugin that transforms variables and specifically asset paths in json files (I'm unaware of such one) or write your own
